# Read configuration file inside docker-compose or in docker file

Tags: docker

Is it possible to read a configuration file e.g. json or yml file inside docker-compose and then parse the file and install the libraries listed in that file. For example

modules.json

```
{
  "base": {
  },
  "myproject": {
    "apcu": "php-apcu",
    "memcache": "php-memcache",
    "xmlrpc": "php-xmlrpc",
    "mysql": "php-mysql",
    "gd": "php-gd",
    "soap": "php-soap",
    "zip": "php-zip"
  }
}
```

And then have this referenced in the .env file like
MODULE=myproject

Inside the DockerFile I would then like to do

```
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install php-apcu
```

etc?

Answer (score 1):

In Dockerfile you should:

1. install the jq package to manipulate with json.
2. copy your .json file into container
3. install needed dependencies

Dockerfile example:

```
RUN apt-get install -y jq
COPY modules.json .
RUN cat modules.json | jq .myproject[] | sed -e 's/"//g' -e "s/'//g" | xargs apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install
```